# Precise definition of a p-value

Tags: self-study, p-value

We are given the following experiment:

Consider an experiment which is a Bernoulli trial: it either succeeds with probability p
or fails with probability 1− p; trials are independent of one another.
Throughout this question we specify a null hypothesis H0 : p =
1/
2
, and an alternative
hypothesis HA : p =
2/
3
.
We perform the experiment 50 times, and our observation is r = 33 successes and 17
failures. Only one-sided tests are considered here.

We are asked to give a **precise definition of the p-value**. I don't understand what the question is asking really but I attempted it.

Attempt:

```
> dbinom(33,50,0.66)
[1] 0.1184165]

Our p-value is greater than 0.5 meaning we reject the null hypothesis.
```

Am I answering the question correctly or did I misunderstand the question entirely?

Comment: You does not seem to give *any* definition, so if you are asked to give a precise one, then it sounds like you missed the point...

Comment: Thanks. Would a better attempt be : "We have more extreme results than the given null hypothesis"

Comment: You probably should start with reading some of the answers for the other questions tagged as [tag:p-value] (starting from the most up-voted ones) and then try giving the *definition* by yourself.

Comment: I don't understand how you can be given that Ho and Ha.  It seems like a false dichotomy to me...  But in any case, when using the binom.test function, the probability you would use is the probability for the null hypothesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you have attempted to provide a "definition". To define something is to specify the nature and meaning of it. Try answering this question: What is a p-value? (Note that it is not essential to calculate a p-value in order to define it.)

See here: [What is the meaning of p values and t values in statistical tests?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-is-the-meaning-of-p-values-and-t-values-in-statistical-tests)